# How to get entity by specific field (not primary key)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, repository, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I have done get data by `Id` (primary key) with success. But if I call `Get` by another field, why is it always `Id` that is used?

[image: search with id(primary key)]

[image: Search with id_kategori(not_primary_key]

Here is my code:

**ITempatAppService.cs**

```
public interface ITempatAppService:IApplicationService
{
    GetTempatOutput GetTempatById(GetTempatInput input);

    GetTempatOutput GetTempatByIdKategori(GetTempatKategori input);
}
```

**GetTempatInput.cs**

```
public class GetTempatInput
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**GetTempatOutput.cs**

```
public class GetTempatKategori
{
    public int IdKategori { get; set; }
}
```

**TempatAppService.cs**

```
public class TempatAppService:ApplicationService,ITempatAppService
{
    private readonly ITempatManager _tempatManager;
    public TempatAppService(ITempatManager tempatManager)
    {
        _tempatManager = tempatManager;
    }

    public GetTempatOutput GetTempatById(GetTempatInput input)
    {
        var getTempat = _tempatManager.GetTempatById(input.Id);
        GetTempatOutput output = Mapper.Map<MasterTempat, GetTempatOutput>(getTempat);
        return output;
    }

    public GetTempatOutput GetTempatByIdKategori(GetTempatKategori input)
    {
        var getTempat = _tempatManager.GetTempatByIdKategori(input.IdKategori);
        GetTempatOutput output = Mapper.Map<MasterTempat, GetTempatOutput>(getTempat);
        return output;
    }
}
```

Here is my **TempatManager.cs**:

```
public class TempatManager : DomainService, ITempatManager
{
    private readonly IRepository<MasterTempat> _repositoryTempat;
    public TempatManager(IRepository<MasterTempat> repositoryTempat)
    {
        _repositoryTempat = repositoryTempat;
    }

    public MasterTempat GetTempatById(int Id)
    {
        return _repositoryTempat.Get(Id);
    }

    public MasterTempat GetTempatByIdKategori(int IdKategori)
    {
        return _repositoryTempat.Get(IdKategori);
    }
}
```

Comment: by default it takes Id as a parameter, You can make a call something like `(x => x.IdKategori = input.IdKategori )`

Comment: where i put that sir? @viveknuna

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVZHD.png   @viveknuna

Comment: Wherever you are calling `GetAll` or similar method in your code

Comment: post `_tempatManager.GetTempatByIdKategori` method implementation

Comment: you have a problem in TempatManager . Show your TempatManager and I'll point you the problem.

Comment: That's my tempat manager , please help me. @AlperEbicoglu

Comment: see you have the problem in TempatManager. Thanks @aaron

Comment: I want to ask again . I'm success to get data with id kategori , but only one data can show , how can i show all data with same id kategori? @AlperEbicoglu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming the parameter `IdKategori` doesn't make it search by that column. Do this:

```
public MasterTempat GetTempatByIdKategori(int IdKategori)
{
    return _repositoryTempat.GetAll().First(t => t.IdKategori == IdKategori);
}
```

Comment: Thanks aaron you save my life twice :)

Answer (score 0):

To take the list of the selected kategori.

```
public List<MasterTempat> GetTempatByIdKategori(int IdKategori)
{
    return _repositoryTempat.GetAll().Where(t => t.IdKategori == IdKategori).ToList();
}
```

Comment: yeah you need to return List<MasterTempat> :) See my updated answer

Comment: Done sir , my reputation less than 15